# RTNETLINK answers: Cannot assign requested address

Tags: ip, ip-address, synology

```
161: ovs_bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1
    link/ether 00:11:32:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.20/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global ovs_bond0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
162: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none 
    inet 10.8.0.1 peer 10.8.0.2/32 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
164: vdsm@ovs_bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1
    link/ether 56:25:46:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.206/32 scope global vdsm
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.0.209/32 scope global vdsm
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
ash-4.4# ip addr del 192.168.0.206/32 dev ovs_bond0
RTNETLINK answers: Cannot assign requested address
```

can't delete 192.168.0.206 from ovs_bond0

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by running these commands:

```
ip addr del 192.168.0.206/32 dev vdsm
ip addr del 192.168.0.209/32 dev vdsm
```